# MSMQ multiple queues or single queue?

Tags: .net, client-server, msmq

I have a server client model whereby the clients will have about 100 classes that need to send data to their counterpart at the server side. (There will be 200 classes if there's two clients connected.)

Question, should I have a single queue for each class created (100 queues for 1 client),

**or**

one queue for one client which the receiver will peek the queue and receive only if its own message.

Which approach is more viable? The data is coming in roughly 1 message every 15 seconds per class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's all about message priority. If certain message types are more *important* than others, then it makes sense to create separate queues for them.

So, a third option would be to create a few queues, and send messages based on priority. Messages of the same priority go into the same queue.

If clients need to listen to replies, they should probably have their own queues as well.